# Django import error when running GAE app on python sdk

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Im trying to migrate from GAE to ec2, but to use appscale i need my app to run on just the sdk. when i run it, i get "ImportError: No module named django.core.exceptions".

I went through all of the steps here:
stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core

What else could it be? Django and py27 are installed and working in the shell. The path looks correct as well.

What could prevent django from loading? Why would my app run on GAE but not on the sdk?

Thanks

Comment: What version of python are you using? Can you expand a little about your configuration and other relevant stuff (the question is missing some core information)

Comment: Sure. I'm using py27, and the app works when posted to google. however this error occurs when ran locally on the sdk on windows. As mentioned, all of the steps in the other post have been followed and import django in a python shell returns no errors. What other info would be helpful to you? thanks for your response

Comment: I resolved this, turns out that the GAE SDK 1.9.1 has this issue, but 1.8.1 does not. and appscale is based on 1.8.1. so installing the old sdk on my local machine fixed the issue

Comment: ok, i lied. turned out the newer sdk only raised an error before that line. and when i fixed it, the error persisted. is there any way to import django on gae without using the libraries tag in app.yaml?